# How to add language link to a Wikipedia page

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, wiki

I'm trying to add an *interlanguage link* to a Wikipedia page. I've read the instructions given in [wikipedia:wikidata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikidata) page, but couldn't get to add the language links.

Here is what I'm trying to do: When I click on the **Add link** button in the left side, it shows a `you need to be logged in` pop-up and redirects me to the central data repository (Wikidata) user login page. When I sign-in, it takes me to the Wikidata homepage which I've no clue on what to do. Then, I just tried to search the Wikidata for the page and found the item. At the bottom of the item I've added the *french language Wikipedia* entry.

But when I open the original Wikipedia page, there is no link to the french page in the languages column. And now, when I click on the **Add links** button, it again shows the login popup.

Is there any thing that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you give a link to the specific page you did this on?

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteenth-Century_French_Studies)

Comment: Comments are temporary. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikidata takes some time before changes are propagated to the respective wikis. In fact, the page that you were trying to edit already has got the French link that you were looking to add in.

The update schedule can be monitored [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:DispatchStats).